# How can I get WiFi drivers for RTL8822CE on my Arch?

Tags: arch-linux, wifi, drivers, realtek

I have `Network controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8822CE 802.11ac PCIe Wireless Network Adapter` integrated with my motherboard.
I'm trying to find drivers, and I come across [this package](https://github.com/tomaspinho/rtl8821ce).
However, this package doesn't work, it gives me this error:

```
About to run dkms install steps...
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /usr/src/rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325/dkms.conf does not exist.
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /usr/src/rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325/dkms.conf does not exist.
Error! Could not locate dkms.conf file.
File: /usr/src/rtl8821ce-v5.5.2_34066.20200325/dkms.conf does not exist.
Finished running dkms install steps.
```

And I came across [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1299429/20-04-how-to-downgrade-kernel-from-5-4-0-56-generic-to-5-4-0-55-61).
Their solution was to use `dpkg-reconfigure`. I tried looking for an Arch equivalent to it, and its containing package `debconf`, until I came to the realization there may not be any Arch equivalent of either.

I also did try the steps detailed [here](https://miloserdov.org/?p=5930) which pretty much uses the same package.
Here's some info:

- Kernel Version: `5.10.46-1-lts`
- Hardware Model: HP HP ENVY TE01-0xxx
- Processor: Intel® Core™ i7-8700 CPU @ 3.20GHz × 12
- OS Type: 64-bit

  Thanks so much (this mobile-data is so painful).
  Cheers!

Comment: Yes. I did try to install through the AUR (as someone in my last post recommended I do), that's what the tutorial I link to uses in the section about installing on Arch.

Comment: Revised question w/ more details on DEV: https://dev.to/baenencalin/how-can-i-get-wifi-to-work-on-my-installation-of-arch-mobile-data-s-killing-me-cdh.

Comment: Try install  the "firmware-realtek". for your distrubtion. For Debian it's "apt install firmware-realtek".

Comment: @CinaedSimson I tried `sudo yay -S firmware-realtek` but it says it says that the target (`firmware-realtek`) couldn't be found.

Comment: @CinaedSimson I'm on Arch.

Comment: Have you tried "yay -S debtap" - see "https://ostechnix.com/convert-deb-packages-arch-linux-packages/". You might want to bounce this off the Arch Linux blogs. I only know that it exists - I've never used it - and I know next to nothing about Arch Linux.

Comment: @CinaedSimson So... I installed it. Now what?
I don't have a deb package for `firmware-realtek`. How/Where can I download it?

Thanks for your help so far.

Comment: As mentioned previously, I don't know anything about it - and I know nothing about Arch Linux. But when went to the Debian website, there was a tar file with drivers located here: http://deb.debian.org/debian/pool/non-free/f/firmware-nonfree/firmware-nonfree_20210315.orig.tar.xz - which is all you need.